# Как корректно реализовать метод?

Tags: c#

Мне по заданию нужно, чтобы метод LiftingPower() был абстрактым. Как корректнее мне реализовать  метод LiftingPower() в классе Motorcycle? Метод должен устанавливать грузоподъемность, но перед этим спрашивать про наличие коляски у мотоцикла. Если ее нету, то присваивать грузоподьемности значение 0. Мой вариант реализации метода мне не сильно нравиться.
        abstract class Carrier
        {
            private string model;
            private string number;
            private double speed;
            protected double liftPower;

```
        private bool SpeedIsNotCorrect(double tempSpeed)
        {
            return tempSpeed > 0.0;
        }

        private bool ModelIsNotCorrect(string tempModel)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempModel);
        }

        private bool NumberIsNotCorrect(string tempNumber)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempNumber);
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get
            {
                return model;
            }

            set
            {

                do
                {
                    model = value;
                }while(ModelIsNotCorrect(model));
            }
        }

        public double Speed
        {
            get
            {
                return speed;
            }

            set
            {
                do
                {
                    speed = value;
                }while(!SpeedIsNotCorrect(speed));
            }
        }

        public string Number
        {
            get
            {
                return number;
            }

            set
            {
                do
                {
                    number = value;
                } while (NumberIsNotCorrect(number));
            }
        }

        abstract public void DecsribeCarrier();
        abstract public double LiftingPower();
    }
class Car : Carrier
    {
        public Car(string mod, string num, double lPower) 
        {
            Model = mod;
            Number = num;
            liftPower = lPower;
        }

        public override double LiftingPower()
        {
            return liftPower; 
        }

        public override void DecsribeCarrier()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Это легковая машина марки {0} с номером {1} имеет скорость {2} км/час. ", Model, Number, Speed);
        }
    }

class Motorcycle : Carrier
    {
        public Motorcycle(string mod, string num)
        {
            Model = mod;
            Number = num;
        }

        public override void LiftingPower()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("К мотоциклу прицеплена каляска? - y/n");
            string avaibalitySideCar = Console.ReadLine();
            if (avaibalitySideCar == "y")
            {
                liftPower = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                liftPower = 2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Средняя грузодъемность мотоцикла {0} тон", liftPower); 
            return liftPower;
        }

        public override void DecsribeCarrier()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Это мотоцикл марки {0} с номером {1} имеет скорость {2}", Model, Number, Speed);
        }
```

Comment: ИМХО, нормально реализован метод (в рамках поставленной задачи), только строка "return liftPower" - лишняя, метод-то void. 
Если хотите более внятного ответа - то либо уточните требования к задаче, либо скажите, что именно вам не нравится.
P.S. обращения к консоли я бы спрятал в отдельный класс, чтобы класс мотоцикла не зависел от консоли, но, повторюсь, все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Уменьшите количество кода и уточните, что именно вам не нравится.

Comment: Ретурн не лишний, так как метод в базовом классе объявлен, как возвращающий значение double. Следовательно код не скомпилится с воидом - подозреваю это опечатка. По использованию консоли +1